# How to display ActionBar in the entire App Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-actionbar

Hello i'm making an application for Android and I added an ActionBarDrawerToggle  to the app. When i select an item, the ActionBarDrawerToggle disappear.

What I want to do :
Create the ActionBarDrawerToggle in MainWindow.java [Done]
Create Profil.java and Planning.java and extend MainWindow into Profil and Planning to display the ActionBarDrawerToggle. [Problem]

I'm using :

**UPDATE**

**Mainactivity** :

```
   public  class  MainWindow extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainwindow);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainwindow, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.nav_profil) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_profil) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profil.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_planning) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**the Profil** :

```
    public class Profil extends MainWindow {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_profil);
        System.out.println("Profil");
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.main">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainWindow"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mainwindow"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Connection"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Profil"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `Profil` has a `NoActionBar` theme, so it's not going to have an `ActionBar` unless you set one.

Comment: Thank you, i removed it but it doesn't display the actionbar with the menu

I'm using a this : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xiprox/Material-Action-Bar-Sample/master/screenshots/1.png

And after the removing it display this (with no icon) : http://www.jayway.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/intended-result1.png

Comment: `Profil` also has to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method to have the menu.

Comment: I added the onCreate method

Comment: Your posted code shows the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method in `MainActivity`. If you want the menu in the `Profil` Activity as well, you need to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method in `Profil`, too.

Comment: Check the new edit now and tell me if it's like this

Comment: Yep. What's the problem, exactly? The ActionBar isn't there, or the Menu isn't there?

Comment: The Menu isn't here :/
It shows this : http://techlovejump.com/wp-content/uploads/device-2015-01-31-233057.png
But i want this : https://dabx.io/content/images/2015/01/material-design-spinner-toolbar-style-fix/cover_image.png
what i'm already using in mainwindow with these 3 "_" on the left

Comment: Yeah, that's not a menu. That's the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Comment: I'm using it in the mainactivity and I would show it in Profil too and everywhere

Comment: Then either create it separately in each Activity you want it in, or create a base Activity that has it, and extend your Activities from that. If all your Activities already extend `Mainwindow`, just set it up in that.

Comment: Well, i wanted to extend Mainwindow that only contain the ActionBarDrawerToggle for the others Activities, 

So i did : 

public class Profil extends MainWindow  {[...]}


But i got an error : This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Can you tell me how to extend the MainWindow correctly into the Profil class to use this ActionBarDrawerToggle in Profil too ?

Comment: Call `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);` before `setContentView()` in `Mainwindow`.

Comment: The error has disappeared and I can now go to the Profil but the ActionBarDrawerToggle disappear when i open the Profil
I'll update my 1st post.

Comment: You can't call `setContentView()` again in `Profil`, or it'll replace the entire layout you set up in `Mainwindow`. Instead, inflate whatever additional layout `Profil` needs, and add it to the `DrawerLayout`'s content `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a material support lib you will have to add the action bar manually in the XML file

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and in the java Activity file in onCreate() method add the following lines

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Ok i found this just remove the line setContentView(R.layout.content_profil); form your Profil class and see

Answer (score 0):

> Be sure @style/AppTheme theme not NoActionBar.